# Android: random number from range

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm fairly new to Android developing, and I've been assigned to make an app that displays random numbers. Now, this is a topic which is fairly popular on the internet, but none of the results I find features a specific amount of random numbers, from a specific range of numbers.

I'm using these objects

```
Button mBtnCalculate; //calculates on click
EditText mEtxtFirst; //first number of range
EditText mEtxtLast; //last number of range
EditText mEtxtAmount; //# of numbers to output
TextView mTxtvResult; //where it should output to
```

All EditTexts are converted to integer values on click.

Comment: if you have more than one random just call random multiple times?

Comment: I'm not even that far yet, I don't have a clue how I could do it. I'm going for a for-loop the length of my mEtxtAmount, but from there i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using 
[`Random.nextInt(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29):

```
Random r = new Random();
//...
int aNumber = low + r.nextInt(high-low+1); //+1 if high is inclusive
```

Answer (score 0):

try using math.random()*the size of your range + min

random number between 50 and 100

```
int Max = 100;
int Min = 50;
int num;
int size = 10;

for (int i = size; --i>0;)
     num = Min + (int)Math.random()*(Max-Min) ;
```